# Flat File Destination does not save error rows - SSIS

Tags: error-handling, ssis, flatfiledestination

Inside a fooreachloop I've got the next configuration in my ssis package:

[image]

As you can see, from my source I've got some rows with some problems. With the data viewer I can see them. In theory the flat file destination should record this values on the file indicated by the connector. But instead of that in the destination file I can only see the header and not the values.

[image]

From the Staging DB destination the errors are configured with the option of "Redirect Rows"

So, what can be missing in the configuration?

Comment: It is used only to show the destination flat file with the header and not more information. The rows showed in the data viewer do not appear at the end of the process.

Comment: Are you in a foreach loop or something that could be re-initializing the Flat File Destination?

Comment: Yes  @billinkc I am reading different files inside a foreachloop. What is the option that I'd have to set in order to avoid this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flat file destination is probably set to truncate, not append. so the lack of data at the end of the loop is probably an indication that the last file succeed with no issues.

If you notice your data viewer is paused, which means that those rows have not yet been flushed to the destination file, so both at the end of execution, and at the precise location the screenshot was taken, i'd expect the file to be empty.

The flat file connection has a "Overwrite data in the file" option to change this behavior, but you many need to manually truncate the file before the first loop other wise you get yesterdays and todays errors in the one file..